Restricting a Firebase Function to just registered users
I have a v2 firebase callable function:
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

/// Simple ping to test authentication
exports.ping = onCall(async (req) => {
    return { pong: true };
});


Because it's a callable function, it requires authentication. I have verified that this works as expected: if I call the function without an Authorization header, I get a 401 Unauthorized. If I call it with a valid authorization bearer token, i successfully get back {pong: true}
But it doesn't seem to matter if my authorization token is for a user of my app or not. I would like to restrict access to this callable function only to registered users of my app. Currently, I have no registered users in https://console.firebase.google.com/project/XXX/authentication/users

Despite that, I'm still able to successfully call ping as long as I have a valid token for a google user. The user console is still empty before and after the call, yet the call succeeds.
How do I restrict my v2 firebase callable functions to only be usable by users listed in my users console?

Authentication information is automatically passed along to a Callable Cloud Function, but it is not automatically enforced. So your Cloud Functions code will still need to check whether a user is signed in, as explained and shown in the documentation on writing and deploying the callable function. From there:

The request parameter contains data passed from the client app as well as additional context like authentication state. For a callable function that saves a text message to the Realtime Database, for example, data could contain the message text, along with auth information in auth:
// Message text passed from the client.
const text = request.data.text;
// Authentication / user information is automatically added to the request.
const uid = request.auth.uid;
const name = request.auth.token.name || null;
const picture = request.auth.token.picture || null;
const email = request.auth.token.email || null;


So you'll want to check whether request.auth has a value, or any other authorization check that is relevant for your use-case.
